# Terraform change file layout

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops

Hello i have 3 files in my terraform directory

vpc.tf aerospike-ec2.tf vars.tf

and here is contents of vpc.tf file

```
resource "aws_vpc" "wizzair-dev-qa-vpc" {
  cidr_block = var.wizzair-dev-qa-vpc_cidr
  tags = {
    Environment = "dev-qa"
    Name = "wizzair-aws-vpc"
    Project = "Network"
  }
}


data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}


resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnets" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.wizzair-dev-qa-vpc.id
  cidr_block        = var.subnet_cidr
  availability_zone = "eu-north-1a"
  tags = {
    Environment = "dev-qa"
    Project = "Network"
    Name = "wizzair-aws-subnet-private"
  }
}
```

here is my aerospike.tf file

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "private" {
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.private_subnets.id
  private_ips     = ["10.249.10.4"]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.aerospike_traffic.id, aws_security_group.general.id]
  tags = {
    Environment = "dev"
    Project = "wizzair"
    Name = "aerospike-interface"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "dev-wizzair-aerospike" {
  ami = "ami-077b12cf33hb9a995"
  availability_zone = "eu-north-1a"
  instance_type = "t3.large"
  key_name = "${var.generated_key_name}"
  network_interface {
     device_index=0
     network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.private.id
  }
  tags = {
    Environment = "dev"
    Project = "wizzair"
    Name = "aerospike-instance-dev"
  }
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "dev-wizzair-aerospike-ebs" {
  availability_zone = "eu-north-1a"
  size              = 10
  tags = {
    Environment = "dev"
    Project = "wizzair"
    Name = "aerospike-volume"
  }
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "dev-wizzair-aerospike-ebs-att" {
  device_name = "/dev/sdh"
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.dev-wizzair-aerospike-ebs.id
  instance_id = aws_instance.dev-wizzair-aerospike.id
}
```

and vars.tf

```
variable "wizzair-dev-qa-vpc-cidr" {
  default = "10.249.10.0/24"
}
```

and if the files are in the same directory, then everything works, but if I create the aerospike directory and transfer the aerospike.tf file there, then go to the aerospike directory and enter terraform plan there, then an error occurs

```
mkdir aerospike && mv aerospike.tf aerospike && cd aerospike && terraform plan
terraform plan
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on main.tf line 2, in resource "aws_network_interface" "private":
│    2:   subnet_id       = aws_subnet.private_subnets.id
│
│ A managed resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnets" has not been declared in the root module.
```

i've heard about state outputs, but how to deal with it in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just randomly move files to sub-folders. You have to construct [TF modules](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop) for that, which you then have to appropriately call and use in your parent script.